# Raspberry Pi 3 ubuntu mate Failed to start load kernel modules

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi

I have installed Ubuntu MATE on Raspberry Pi3 and it works, but on startup I see this message

```
Failed to start load kernel modules
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

I did already `apt-get update && sudo-apt get upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`

I also tried to follow [This guide on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318779&p=13466943#post13466943).

[image: load.service information]

Comment: here's the answer (same modules as threw errors for me) [Kernel load module error during boot up](//askubuntu.com/a/795421)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got `/etc/modules` empty, but how can I access `cups configuration file` ?

Comment: Got it: `sudo nano /etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf`

Comment: Ok now it boots up without errors! Thank you Zanna :) great work. I am very happy to join ubuntu community. Farewell Windows!!

Comment: Awesome, glad that helped :)

Comment: how can I give + to a person here?

Comment: By upvoting posts that helped you, but you don't have enough reputation to do that yet. It's ok though :)